# SQL allocating too much memory for specific table

Tags: mysql, memory, innodb

As I'm showing in the picture, for one specific table there is too much allocation of memory in DB server.

[image]

If you see, there is no much data visible, the xml column data is hardly about 100kb.

What might be the reason for this ? I don't need a solution. I can just drop it and create the table again. What what is the reason for this ?